# Grails/Hibernate Cache unpredictable

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, caching

I only resort to StackOverflow when I've really tried everything but I just cannot figure out how to solve this problem. It is quite easy to replicate, basically I have a table (basically just a key/value table where I keep settings).

```
class SystemSetting {
    Group settingGroup
    String key
    String value
    String label
    String type

    Date lastUpdated
    Date dateCreated
}
```

I have a simple controller which allows me to update these settings (@Transactional annotation) and 'flush: true' on the save.

Now, lets say I set an option from true to false (or any change) once this change is made, it is not reflected on other processes/sessions.

The code to read a setting is the following:

```
SystemSetting setting = SystemSetting.find("FROM SystemSetting ss WHERE ss.settingGroup = :group AND ss.key = :key",
            [group: group, key: key]
        );
```

So for example, in browser A) I update a setting. In browser B (or curl) when I view/access this setting it still has the old value.

I have disabled all the caching I know of:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = false
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
    flush.mode = 'manual' // OSIV session flush mode outside of transactional context
}

grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false
```

But these results are still easily duplicated. What/why/where is this option being cached and how to I invalidate it?

This is really not leaving me with a warm feeling inside as it creates tons of issues if I can't be confident of what data will be coming out of the database :(

Using Grails 2.5.1 (and tested on 2.4.4, same result).

**UPDATE:**

I have been able to duplicate this in a fresh application.

Application is available here: https://github.com/donald-jackson/grails-async-error-demo

To duplicate:

1. Clone the repository and configure the datasource to use your local MySQL.
2. 'run-app' in Grails and visit /AsyncErrorTest/systemSetting
3. Create a setting with optionName = 'testOption' set value to true (or false)
4. Using curl (or other browser) visit /AsyncErrorTest/systemSetting/showVariable a few times, change the variable value and you will see the output correctly reflects the changes.
5. Change the value of 'testOption' again.
6. Call /AsyncErrorTest/systemSetting/showVariableAsync a few times using curl and you will notice the variable will start changing its value between the current and previous.
7. Once you notice this behaviour you can check in your browser or even on the original showVariable method and it will also give unreliable output.

Comment: "Now, lets say I set an option from true to false" - What kind of option are you talking about setting?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown an instance of SystemSetting. 'True'/'False' was just an example, lets say systemSettingInstance value property is 'x' then from the mentioned controller I call systemSettingInstance.setValue('y'); and systemSettingInstance.save(flush:true); - in the second browser/curl the value will still be returned as 'x'.

Comment: The behavior described here doesn't make sense to me.  I understand what you are saying, just not sure why it might happen.  If you can create a sample app which demonstrates that problem we can take a look.  I would investigate if the database is receiving the update and investigate if the query to retrieve the instance later really is going to the db, as opposed to the instance coming out of a cache that is supposed to be disabled, or something along those lines.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'll see if I can duplicate it in a very specific case and share with you. Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you testing the update? Only from browser? Given this sounds like a boolean (true/false), I want to exclude that this is a form submission issue. Be aware that HTML checkboxes only submit when checked. Is this also happening from text fields or if hardcoded from controller for example?

Comment: @drrob He hasn't shown enough code to know for sure but if he is using the built in data binding mechanisms and the built in GSP tags for creating checkboxes, the `false` checkbox handling stuff is all accounted for by the framework.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I am using the built in data bindings and GSP tags for the forms. I think I confused matters by giving true/false as an example because I'm actually talking about storing strings here (value field). Think of it as a String field being updated by Browser A, then having a second request with a different/no session not reflecting the update.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Here are some basic screenshots to show the process, I created a simple method in my controller to simply show the state of a variable.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Here is the code (which refers to the SQL query in my original post): https://www.dropbox.com/s/696crj8cxkjjwoe/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2012.02.19.png?dl=0 - So variable starts off as the String 'False': https://www.dropbox.com/s/iif8feozvk3xp4j/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2012.05.40.png?dl=0 - then I change it to True https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2w71qdo5gz12a7/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2011.59.59.png?dl=0 - confirm change: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilbdjg7gz30c7uc/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2011.59.08.png?dl=0.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Database reflects change as well. Then I call the code via cURL - https://www.dropbox.com/s/i3wrh2tdwaksnzx/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2012.00.25.png?dl=0 - still reflecting false. No idea why. If I hit this page numerous times some will be false some will be true, almost at random but I'm sure there is an explanation somewhere.

Comment: Here is a further illustration of the randomness after the update: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sadeophiymc5lh/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2012.33.21.png?dl=0 - You can see these curl requests in succession some returning the string 'false' from the find query some returning the string 'true'. To be clear, these are not boolean variables, I'm referring to the String value field in the original post.

Comment: What is inside of `settingsService.getSettingValue(...)`?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but you don't need to cal `.booleanValue()` on the the object returned from `Boolean.valueOf(...)`.  You can just use the object returned from `Boolean.valueOf(...)` as your boolean expression in Groovy.

Comment: Seeing screenshots of HTML forms isn't going to help troubleshoot your problem.  Runnable code would.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown OK I've made some progress here. I created 2 methods, looking like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7rzpzw3lprmae0h/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2015.27.54.png?dl=0 - if I only use the non-Async version of this (showVariable) it works as I expect it to (no caching etc). If I call the Async version I start getting mixed results (variable value flipping) - not even only in the Async method though - in both methods subsequent to an Async request. I have no idea why this could be but I'm assuming due to some Async thread not being flushed somewhere. Have you experienced this before?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown for the record here are the contents of those methods you asked for : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf27t54oyb76m0x/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2015.30.16.png?dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/s/ta8114v1pnbyo7s/Screenshot%202015-08-15%2015.30.48.png?dl=0 - I do appreciate your time.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I've edited the main question with steps to duplicate and code as well. Hopefully this helps someone else one day.

Comment: Your question here indicates that you have disabled the second level cache in Hibernate but the code in your project has it enabled (see https://github.com/donald-jackson/grails-async-error-demo/blob/7b68840a5009505fff73cf88bbc8a56a5736b4b7/grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy#L16).  Is that intentional?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown sorry I just created a new project and it had those defaults set. With that said, it makes no difference, the behaviour is the same.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown thanks for your time so far, I'm relatively certain now this is a bug either with Tomcat or Grails with regards to Async processing, do you know where/how I can report this?

Comment: If you think it is a Grails bug report it at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was reported to Grails issues and was fixed in Grails 2.5.2.

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9198